# lubuntu 13.10 flash video doesn't display (youtube)

Tags: lubuntu, video, flash, youtube

I have an old pc 256mb ram and 1.6GHz processor which had win xp. It could play youtube videos with chrome (ok it stucked a bit) and i installed lubuntu 13.10. I installed the flashplayer plugin but it can't show any flash video neither play a flash game. It just shows an empty space. I have flashplayer plugin active and updated. What can i do?

Comment: Can you try installing `lubuntu-restricted-extras` from the software center and then try again?

Comment: with `sudo apt-get install lubuntu-restricted-extras` ?

Comment: yes, you could even install it using the terminal.